# How do I leverage ElasticSearch/Solr search API on Titan graph server?

Tags: solr, lucene, elasticsearch, titan

This question puzzles me a lot...

We are using Titan graph server (and it's a great graph DB) and need to leverage ElasticSearch/Solr search API to perform advanced search features on top of the graph server.

I know Titan uses ElasticSearch as its index backend, but [the indexes are created in a different way than ElasticSearch](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/aureliusgraphs/OS4Lsf-QsFg/XtVl0l294FYJ). To perform search queries, I can only use API exposed by Titan other than directly calling ElasticSearch API, thus no way to utilize features like hit highlighting, pagination etc.

I've been thinking about several workaround but unfortunately none of them seems ideal:

- Modifying the index created by Titan using [ElasticSearch update API](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html) -but seems require a lot more "manual" development on our end
- Using Solr as the index backend - but Titan does not support Solr index backend at this time
- Importing Titan graph data into Solr for indexing - but I am not able to find an existing Solr method that can do the work. Also, something like [a JDBC Driver for graph DB](http://www.neo4j.org/develop/tools/jdbc) would also work for me but thinking this might not be the case for Titan.

Anyone here have better ideas how should I proceed? Been researching about it recently but stuck here. Any suggestions highly appreciated!

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Copying the ES index into Solr? Solr is currently not supported, but we are working on that. You can also go against ES directly with some id-conversion (see mailing list for details).

Comment: @MatthiasBroecheler whoops, sorry about the confusion.

Comment: @MatthiasBroecheler Let's forget about the Solr thing first. I did see the post about id-conversion to use ES API directly. But Titan exposes only one property of a vertex/edge, so how can I handle the properties that are missing? E.g. here is the structure of one vertex index Titan created for `GraphOfTheGods`: `{"_index": "titan", "_type": "vertex", "_id": "k", "_score": 1, "_source": {"1k": 4500}}`. Apparently `1k` is actually the "age", however properties "type" and "name" are not showing in the index document. How can I still go against ES and search for those missing properties?

Comment: @MatthiasBroecheler I found the answer for my question here: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/aureliusgraphs/TDr0wr71JFo/MKYbChi6m9MJ, many thanks.

Comment: I wants to use titandb with my custom indexing logic & analyzer. But i have no idea how to do it, not getting any such use-case/example. while searching saw your post here. If you know how to put custom indexing logic & analyzer while searching the data in titandb to improve the search result, please let me know. High level knowledge/use-cases/any link which describes above idea will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

To give a general update to this question, solr is now supported inside titan - http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/0.5.4/solr.html